# Why having both get and elementData methods for an ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

I am studying the implementation of `ArrayList` in `java.util`, and plenty of methods seem to be useless for me, they just make the code more difficult to read. For instance:

```
public E get(int index) {
    rangeCheck(index);

    return elementData(index);
}


 E elementData(int index) {
    return (E) elementData[index];
}
```

Why not cast `elementData` in `public E get(int index)` directly?

Do these extra rounds lead to worse performance? (besides extra work and worse readability)

Comment: I don't understand why this question is being downvoted; I see a well formatted, well asked and clear question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why not cast elementData in public E get(int index) directly?

Because elementData method use more then one place:

```
public E set(int index, E element) {
   ...
   E oldValue = elementData(index);

public E remove(int index) {
   ...
   E oldValue = elementData(index);

public E set(int index, E e) {
   ...
   E oldValue = ArrayList.this.elementData(offset + index);

public E get(int index) {
   ...
   return ArrayList.this.elementData(offset + index);
```

It's ugly and bad Java prictise to write `(E) elementData[index]` everywhere, for example `(E) ArrayList.this.elementData[offset + index]`, small method in Java better then copypast.

> Do these extra rounds lead to worse performance?

Nop, JVM can optimize this small method's call and divided to small method in Java better then saving a irreducible small time for calling method.

Comment: You could simply use `(E) elementData` in every method you have listed couldn't you? By the way, what is the point of `ArrayList.this.elementData()` ? These whole practice seem to be overwrought for me.

Comment: According best practice, every method must do one function (or the leass functions as possible), elementData do unchecked conversion Array varible to generic, set and get also has its own function, in Java it's a terrible practice using copypast instead of small method.  More info you can find in, for example, "clean code" book. Also elementData method has @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") annotation, it's important to code inspection, so annotation also need to use in every method.